# Automation in FTPing and file extraction

Tags: c#, xml, automation

A third party source daily FTPs a zip file (which contains xml file) in a given folder on my application server.
Right now, am manually FTPing the sender, download the zip file and extract xml out of it.

If i need to achieve all this programmatically using C#, how do I go about it?
ie.I need to....
1.FTP the sender
2.Download the file
3.Extract the xml and save it to my folder on app server.

Please help.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [FTPWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) and [FTPWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebresponse.aspx) classes. They should have everything you need.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to get downvoted for not answering your questions but C# is probably overkill for this.  You could just get [curl for windows](http://fileforum.betanews.com/detail/cURL-for-Windows/966899018/1) which will download the file for you and then use the command line version of [link text](http://www.7-zip.org/) to unzip it.  Would be about 2 lines of bat script.

```
cd <some dir>
curl ftp://some.ftp/somefiles/archive.zip
7z e archive.zip
```

3 lines with the cd.  If you really want to do it in C# then look at [these](http://aspalliance.com/1187_Building_a_Simple_FTP_Application_Using_C_20) [articles.](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/9ce6c242-c14c-4969-9251-af95e4cf320f/zip--unzip-folders-and-f.aspx)